# leaflet js strange map behavior

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am having some strange behavior with my leafletjs map. I've tried plotting a few polylines between north america and asia, but get the polyline split into two pieces.

Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You did not add any code with your request so it is no easy to respond you correctly

Likely you need to split each polyline in two parts, else they directly jump to the other part of the world passing over the europe. Then try to center the map on the pacific ocean and not in the europe in order to get a better map.